# How to create filter with geohash under lucene

Tags: java, lucene, geohashing

I'm developing a search engine with java lucene 4.3.
I'd like to understand how can I add spatial feature.
Particularly, I'd like to use geohash to start.
I've studied all the online documentation.
I found the following references:

[outdated IBM article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-spatial/)

[Lucene / Solr 4 Spatial deep dive video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L2cUGv0Rebs&list=WL213D3FE6C76473CA)

[SpatialExample from lucene source code](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/lucene/dev/branches/branch_4x/lucene/spatial/src/test/org/apache/lucene/spatial/SpatialExample.java?view=markup)

I've used spatial4j to encode lat/lng in geohash format and add the string into a field of my document when I indexing as the following code

```
String geohash = GeohashUtils.encodeLatLon(lat, lng);
doc.add(new StringField("geohash", geohash, Store.YES));
```

In the search method I want to create a filter with the searching lat/lng parameters, I'm stuck here

```
SpatialContext ctx = SpatialContext.GEO;
int maxLevels = 11;
SpatialPrefixTree grid = new GeohashPrefixTree(ctx, maxLevels); 
SpatialStrategy strategy = new RecursivePrefixTreeStrategy(grid, "geohash");
...
```

What should I do?
Should I create the geohash from searching lat/lng and create a rect to match with like this?

```
String searchGeoHash = GeohashUtils.encodeLatLon(searchlat, searchlng);
Filter filter = strategy.makeFilter(new SpatialArgs(SpatialOperation.Intersects, GeohashUtils.decodeBoundary(searchGeoHash, ctx)));
```

I think that it's wrong. In my mind I think that I should give some string comparison query giving the matching precision to compare geohash strings.

Which is the right way?

This question can be related with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15508459/how-does-geohash-index-work-in-lucene) but it's different.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How do want to search for the feature?  Exact coordinates?   Within bounding box?  Distance from a given point?  Looks like you are trying to match the coordinates exactly, which might not work due to rounding errors.

Comment: No, I don't want to match the exact coordinates. I'd like to understand how to compare 2 geohashes that in my mind are 2 bounding box. I figure out geohash comparison like string matching internally, but maybe that I did not understand it. Anyway, my goal is to compare (intersect or contains) 2 bounding box with geohash with a given precision. Thanks.

Comment: I'm still not clear on what your goal is. The SpatialExample.java you reference should be the ideal code reference on how to use Lucene's spatial module.  Notice it doesn't involve any explicit geohash encoding or decoding, unlike your attempts above.  *Geohashes are an internal detail*, not something you need to know anything about.